# prompt() method works in terminal but not debug console vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prompt

```js
"use strict";

const ps = require("prompt-sync");
const prompt = ps();

let base = prompt("base :");
let height = prompt("height:");
let area = (base * height / 2);
console.log(`The area of triangle is ${area}`);
```

When I run it in the terminal (node filename.js), the code works.

But when I run it in debug console, I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error Error: ENXIO: no such device or address, open '/dev/tty`
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Node.js programs launch in the VS Debug Console, which doesn't support reading from terminal input.

You can change your launch.json configuration to switch the console from the default `internalConsole` to `integratedTerminal`, which solves the issue:

**.vscode/launch.json:**

```
"configurations": [
  ...
  ...
  "console": "integratedTerminal"
  ...
]
```

Relevant documentation:  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_node-console