# I'm using JS in VScode and I'm trying to take user input through prompt cmd, but it's not working. I've already installed prompt-sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, prompt

I'm trying to write a simple code to take input from the user using the prompt cmd with the Node.js debugger in VScode, but nothing appears on the console, as if the code is forever running.

What should I do?

I've already installed prompt-sync via Command Prompt using: `npm install prompt-sync`.

Also, I used `const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();` as recommended by the README.md within the prompt-sync documentation.

However, when I write

```
const name = prompt('Whats your name? ');
console.log(`${name}`)
```

nothing happens on the DEBUG CONSOLE and the code never stops running.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem. "It doesn't work"** isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. **Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question**."_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prompt() method works in terminal but not debug console vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73757818/prompt-method-works-in-terminal-but-not-debug-console-vscode)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved adding

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

to the launch.json in VSCode